# Problems while adding platforms in Cordova/PhoneGap app?

Tags: android, html, cordova, phonegap-build

I have installed Cordova and created my first app using it.
when I give it command to add a platform, it just loading all the time. 
c
`cordova platform add android`

Just a line rotating from last 2 hours.

Comment: Do you have the Android SDK installed and added to your environment?

Comment: plz provide more detail.

Comment: I ve already installed android studio and eclipse.. AND Sdk is in the eclips package...

Comment: So why not just code in native Java/Android since you already have Android Studio?

Comment: I wanna create with HTML as i'm learning java still. Also im making little bit in eclips.:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that android SDK is installed and you have given a correct environment  path in bashhrc file if you are using Linux . and if you are using windows or mac there is phonegap desktop beta version which you can install

Comment: Thanks krishna it fixed. Actually environment path wasn't given. And yes i have phone gap desktop version but I think that doesnt export our app to use in Android Studio.